# Filtering in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, filter

I'm currently following an oldish Angular tutorial on Pluralsight and was told to enter the following code

```
    performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
    filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase;
    return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) => product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase.indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
}
```

Which is supposed to filter a user search. (ie they type the letter 'a', only results containing that letter will display. However, I'm getting a few errors:

1: [ts] Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.
(parameter) filterBy: string

2: [ts] Property 'indexOf' does not exist on type '() => string'.
any

I'm new to typescript and not sure if I'm supposed to be casting these variables or something entirely different.

Comment: kindly show me your IProduct modal because here is the problem while you have to mention productName as string and use simply toLowerCase().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toLocaleLowerCase` is a function, you should call it, the idea is to get the lower case version of the original string:

```
interface IProduct { productName: string}
function performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
    filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) => product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution use `toLowerCase()`

```
performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
    filterBy = filterBy.toLowerCase();
    return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) => product.productName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
}
```